# JasperReport: how to download generated report?

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

I'm developing a web application on which user able to generate reports of some data. I'm using JasperReport do it. It's my first experience with JasperReport. So I've followed this [tutorial](http://java-bytes.blogspot.com/2009/06/jasper-reports-example.html).

Method described there can save reports on server, but I need that report would be downloadable after generation.

Could appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at JasperReports Server. You could use it, since it has the ability to save and download reports. Or you could get ideas for what you need to implement in your own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set these in your servlet code when trying to download the generated file. May need to change some parameters depending on the file format for your specific case.

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
String disHeader = "Attachment;Filename=\"ReportFile.csv" + "\"";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look something like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/reports/report1.jrxml");
            jasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
            System.out.println("Jasper Report : " + jasReport);

            Connection con = MyConnFactory.getConnection();
            System.out.println(con);

            jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasReport,null,con);//, mapParam, con);
            System.out.println("Jasper Print : " + jasPrint);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasPrint, "f:/nn.pdf");
//            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasPrint, baos);
//            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
//            inputStream = bais;

            ServletOutputStream sos=resp.getOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasPrint, sos);

            try {
                MyConnFactory.getConnection().close();
                sos.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyReport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Save the file to a location accessible directly by the client, or
2. Stream the bytes back from a file (or other byte stream).

To do #1, you'll either have to save it "inside" the web app, which isn't possible when deploying a war, and tenuous if deploying an exploded war. Symlinks and container games can work around that.

To do #2, save it anywhere, and create a servlet that can take a request parameter that maps to the generated file (or whatever) and streams it back--searching for "download servlet" gives a ton of implementations.

Most frameworks offer similar functionality without writing a pure servlet.